# how to put toggle in ajax periodical updates

Tags: javascript, ajax, toggle

I have a dynamic page in JSP which pulls data/event from the server. And I have used Ajax to periodically update the page in certain time interval. Now i want to put a toggle(play/pause) button, so that i can pause the automatic update of the page and play it again. Below are my pages-

output page:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>EventMonitoring</title>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
var page = "realTime.jsp";  
function ajax(url,target)  
{  
    // native XMLHttpRequest object  
   document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = 'sending...';  
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
   {  
       req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
       req.onreadystatechange = function() {ajaxDone(target);};  
       req.open("GET", url, true);  
       req.send(null);  
   // IE/Windows ActiveX version  
   } 
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
   {  
       req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
       if (req) 
       {  
           req.onreadystatechange = function() {ajaxDone(target);};  
           req.open("GET", url, true);  
           req.send();  
       }  
   }  
   setTimeout("ajax(page,'scriptoutput')", 60000);  
}  

function ajaxDone(target) 
{  
    // only if req is "loaded"  
    if (req.readyState == 4) 
    {  
    // only if "OK"  
    if (req.status == 200 || req.status == 304) 
    {  
        results = req.responseText;  
        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = results;  
    } 
    else 
    {  
        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML="ajax error:\n" +  
        req.statusText;  
    }  
    }  
}  
</script>  

</head>  
<body onLoad="ajax(page,'scriptoutput')">  
<span id="scriptoutput"></span></p>  
</body>  
</html>
```

1. Dynamic page(which pulls the data from server)

   ```
      <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java"      import="java.sql.*,java.util.*,java.io.*,javax.servlet.jsp.JspException" errorPage="" %>  
    <%@ page import="event.activeMq.*"%>  
    <jsp:include page="../include/adminSessionManager.jsp" />  
    <jsp:useBean id="msg" scope="request" class="event.activeMq.ConsumerTool">  
    <jsp:setProperty name="msg" property="*" />  
    </jsp:useBean>  
    <%  
    MessageBean msgs = msg.getMessages();  
    java.util.Iterator dateList = msgs.getDateTime().iterator();  
    java.util.Iterator atmList = msgs.getAtmId().iterator();  
    java.util.Iterator eventTextList = msgs.getEventText().iterator();  
    java.util.Iterator evtNumList = msgs.getEventNumber().iterator();  
    java.util.Iterator sevList = msgs.getSeverity().iterator();  
    java.util.Iterator genList = msgs.getGenerator().iterator();  
    java.util.Iterator genBldList = msgs.getGeneratorBuildVsn().iterator();  
    java.util.Iterator ssidList = msgs.getSubsystemID().iterator();  
    java.util.Iterator taskList = msgs.getTaskID().iterator();  
    java.util.Iterator uniqueList = msgs.getUniqueEventID().iterator();  
    %>  


   <html>  
   <head>  
   <title>Event Monitoring</title>  
   <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">  

   </script>  

   <script language="javascript">  
      /*gives the branchname and branchcode for bank selected*/  
   </script>  


    </head>  
    <body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" onLoad="document.forms[0].name.focus();">   
    <jsp:include page="../include/header.jsp"/>  

     <table width="100%" height="450"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
       <tr>  
       <td width="220" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#f2f2f2">  
       <jsp:include page="../include/menuManager.jsp" />  
       </td>  
         <td height="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8">  
             <tr>  
               <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
                 <tr>  
                   <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
                     <tr>  
                       <td>&nbsp;</td>  
                     </tr>  
                     <tr>  
                       <td height="1" bgcolor="#999999"></td>  
                     </tr>  
                   </table></td>  
                 </tr>  
                 <tr>  
                   <td height="2"></td>  
                 </tr>  
               </table>  
               <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
                   <tr>  
                     <td><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
                       <tr>  
                         <td width="183" height="19" bgcolor="#373948" class="titlelink"> &nbsp;<span class="title">&nbsp;RealTime Events </span></td>  
                         <td width="148" bgcolor="" class="titlelink"> <font color="#FF0000">&nbsp; </font> </td>  
                         <td width="439" bgcolor="" class="titlelink"><font color="#FF0000">  
                           <%//if(msg != null){  
                           //out.print(msg);  
                           //}%>  
                         </font></td>  
                       </tr>  
                     </table></td>  
                   </tr>  
                   <tr>  
                     <td>  

                     <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#373948">  
                         <tr align="center" bgcolor="#FAFAFA">  
                           <td width="14%">  
                            <form name="f1"action="doAddUser.jsp" method="post">  

                         <table width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ECE9D8">  
                           <%while(dateList.hasNext() || atmList.hasNext() || eventTextList.hasNext() || evtNumList.hasNext() || sevList.hasNext() || genList.hasNext() || genBldList.hasNext() || ssidList.hasNext() || taskList.hasNext() || uniqueList.hasNext()){  
                     String dateTime=(String)dateList.next();  
                     String atmId=(String)atmList.next();  
                     String eventText=(String)eventTextList.next();  
                     String eventNumber=(String)evtNumList.next();  
                     String severity=(String)sevList.next();  
                     String generator=(String)genList.next();  
                     String generatorBuildVsn=(String)genBldList.next();  
                     String subsystemID=(String)ssidList.next();  
                     String taskID=(String)taskList.next();  
                     String uniqueEventID=(String)uniqueList.next();  
                            %>                        
    <tr>   
       <td width="45%"><strong> SubsystemId </strong></td>  
       <td width="55%">  <%=subsystemID%></td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
         <td><strong>Severity</strong></td>  
                                   <td><%=severity%></td>  
                                   </tr>  
                                   <tr>  
                                   <td><strong>TaskID</strong></td>  
                                   <td><%=taskID%>  </td>  
                                   </tr>  
                                   <tr>  
                                   <td><strong>UniqueEventID</strong></td>  
                                   <td><%=uniqueEventID%></td>  
                                   </tr>  
                                   <tr>  
                                   <td><strong>Event Text</strong></td>  
                                   <td><%=eventText%></td>  
                                   </tr>  
                                   <tr>  
                                   <td><strong>Event Number</strong></td>  
                                   <td><%=eventNumber%></td>  
                                   </tr>  
                                   <tr>  
                                   <td><strong>Date Time</strong></td>  
                                   <td><%=dateTime%>  </td>
                                   </tr>  
                                   <tr>  
                                   <td><strong>Generator</strong></td>  
                                   <td><%=generator%></td>  
                                   </tr>  
                                   <tr>  
                                   <td><strong>Generator Build VSN</strong></td>  
                                   <td><%=generatorBuildVsn%></td>  
                                   </tr>  
                                   <tr>  
                                   <td><strong>Atm ID</strong></td>  
                                              <td><%=atmId%></td>  
                                   </tr>  
                                   <tr>  
                                   <td><hr></td>  
                                   <td><hr></td>  
                                   </tr>  

       <%}%>                                 
                         </table>  
                        </form>  
                           </td>  
                         </tr>  
                     </table></td>  
                   </tr>  
               </table></td>  
             </tr>  
         </table></td>  
       </tr>  
     </table></td>         
     </tr>  
     <tr>  
     <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  
     <jsp:include page="../include/footer.html" />  
     </td>  
     </tr>  
     </table>  
     </body>  
     </html>
   ```

Can someone help me how to add play/pause button?Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please properly format your code !

Comment: i format it again,please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) instead of setTimeout. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/cmK6a/1/) an example:

```
<div id="mydivtag">
    <button id="start">start</button>
    <button id="stop">stop</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var intervalId;

var sayHello = function() {
    document.getElementById('start').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('stop').disabled = false;
    intervalId = setInterval(function() { 
        var node = document.createTextNode("hello!");        
        document.getElementById('mydivtag').appendChild(node);
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = sayHello;

document.getElementById('start').onclick = sayHello;    

document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('stop').disabled = true;   
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

​​

Comment: i want to start it on load and then on resume after user click pause

Comment: added wiring up buttons - hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: when i click of start or stop button,its not working,the generated text hello is not stopped.it keeps up running.